# Why does live USB only boot in UEFI mode?

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, uefi, live-usb, bios

I've got a dual boot *Ubuntu18.04/Win10* system with the BIOS set to 'Legacy Boot'. I can boot fine into this system. However my *mkusb* live USB (also 18.04 with persistence) won't boot if I leave the BIOS in 'Legacy Boot' mode.

I can swap the BIOS toggle to 'UEFI Boot' and my *mkusb* live USB will proceed to boot without issue. When I try to boot normally to Ubuntu/Win hard drives the system throws an error along the lines `error: no operating system`, and I have to change the BIOS back to 'Legacy Boot'.

What is going on with my system?

Comment: Are you using default settings in mkusb? does the drive work on other computers in BIOS and UEFI?

Comment: Is this in your hp computer? In that case it could be a problem, that is typical for some hp computers: they are unwilling to boot USB drives via grub in BIOS mode, if there is a GUID partition table, GPT. -- You can make a persistent live drive with the MSDOS partition table (which is *not* the default setting), and try it in your computer.

Comment: @C.S. Cameron I am using the `dus` command of _mkusb_ and utilize all the default settings. On other computers this _mkusb_ live USB will boot in either UEFI and Legacy modes. @sudodus this is different than the other issue I posted. This is a different computer.

Comment: I had a similar occurrence the other day, the persistent drive had the word persistent in the grub.cfg file but would only boot UEFI. I also added the word persistent to /isolinux/txt.cfg and it booted in BIOS OK after.